# Aptana 3 remove bundle (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, aptana

I added `jQuery` bundle in Aptana 3 (Commands -> Bundle development -> Install bundle), but now I want to remove this feature.
From Bundle development menu I don't see any "remove bundle" or similar command, how can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to remove this from your system fairly easily. To verify where your jQuery bundle was installed

1. Open Aptana
2. Go to Window -> Show View -> Other
3. In the section "Studio", there should be a view called "Bundles"
4. Select Bundles to open that view
5. Expand the bundle in question (most likely Javascript jQuery)
6. The first entry will show you where it's installed
7. Note the location and shut down Aptana
8. Go to that location and delete the bundle (or move it out of that directory)
9. Restart Aptana

That *should* remove the jQuery bundle from Aptana Studio 3. I just tried it on my local machine and it worked.