# Edit Keyboard Shortcuts in Aptana's Eclipse Plugin (w.r.t. coffeescript)

Tags: eclipse, coffeescript, aptana

I recently installed the Aptana plugin for Eclipse, to do some Coffeescript development, and I'm loving it, but there's one annoyance that I can't seem to solve. The `Shift+Enter` shortcut used to be "insert a line below the current one", but Aptana decided that it wanted to use that shortcut for "New Function". I want that to go away.

*What I've Tried*

- I looked in the Eclipse Keys preferences page, but there is no mention of "Insert New Function" there.
- I looked at [Aptana Studio 3 SHIFT+ENTER option select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265092/aptana-studio-3-shiftenter-option-select) and that seemed promising, but when I click Commands -> CoffeeScript -> Edit this bundle, nothing happens at all. (For other Commands -> XXX -> Edit this bundle, I get a progress bar that eventually fails at around 5%)

Is there a config file somewhere that I can manually edit, or some other way that I can edit Aptana's key shortcuts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found some helpful info here: [Aptana 3 remove bundle (jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131289/aptana-3-remove-bundle-jquery)

Follow the instructions up to the point where you find the installation point, then go in and delete references to the "New Function" Command in the "rubles".